# Forcing AutoCompleteTextView dropdown List

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I am making an `Async` request to download some data once the data is downloaded i clear the old list  and add the new items in the `onPostExecute()` of the `Async` to the adapter of AutoCompleteTextView  and I call

```
adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But i am not able to show the dropdown again ??
Any suggestion would be most appreciated

Comment: please post the entire onPostExecute() code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it here is the solution

All I needed was to reinitialze the variable and call the notify the dataset has changed

```
arrayAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,newDownloadedList);
AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: @M-WaJeEh : I tried but didnt work so used that, Please read the question first

Comment: @M-WaJeEh: Yes I did came across that but that also didnt help

Answer (score 0):

you can  use this

```
   arrayAdapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String> 
   (this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item,newList);
   AutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
   arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

then call
`AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();`